# Run Typescript + Cypress E2E tests over BrowserStack

Tags: typescript, cypress, browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

I am trying to run cypress E2E test case(written in typescript) on BrowserStack.

Library details:-

```
"typescript": "~4.2.4",
"cypress": "9.5.0",
"browserstack-cypress-cli": "1.14.0"
```

I have provided all details of browserstack.json according to documentation. But I got error

```
Running:  info.spec.ts                                                          (NaN of undefined)

Oops...we found an error preparing this test file:

  > src\integration\TEST\info.spec.ts

The error was:

Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./src/integration/TEST/info.spec.ts
Module build failed (from C:/Windows/cypress_package/9.5.4/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-batteries-included-preprocessor/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: error while parsing tsconfig.json
    at handle (C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-preprocessor\dist\index.js:180:23)
    at finalCallback (C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:257:39)
    at C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:306:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:304:22
    at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:499:39)
    at C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:298:10
    at C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:485:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:482:27
    at C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2818:7
    at done (C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3522:9)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:464:33
    at C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:143:16
    at C:\Windows\cypress_package\9.5.4\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:61:14
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:156:23)
```

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: It's running fine on my local system.

Comment: @DheerajkumarRao did you figure this out? I'm running into the same problem

Comment: @Gisheri Please check tsconfig file. Issue was with tsconfig file.

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting, If I try to extend a tsconfig base, it throws this error, but if I copy the base config and don't use the extend, then it's fine.

Comment: @Gisheri Yes It was issue with extends keyword. browserStack-cypress-cli throw error with this. so I create tsconfig without extends.

Comment: Yes It was issue with extends keyword.  browserStack-cypress-cli throw error with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you have added the base URL in tsconfig.json

Also, do try running it on your local machine once without BrowserStack

Comment: It's running fine on my local system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).